# Can't physically select checkbox the first time through

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-fieldset, jquery-mobile-select

When I test the page and click the checkbox nothing happens.  If I go to another page and come back, the checkbox works.

HTML

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true">
       <input id="checkbox8" name="addTo" data-theme="b" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox8"> add to</label>
</fieldset>
```

JQuery

```
$("input[type = 'checkbox']").change(function(){
        var item=$(this);
        if(item.is(":checked")){    
            $('#myMenu').append( $('<li>').attr('class','ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c ui-li-last').append('test'));
            $('#myMenu').listview('refresh');
        }
        else {
                $( "#myMenu li:last-child" ).remove().closest( "[data-role=listview]" ).listview( "refresh" );  
        }
});
```

Why is that?  I don't want the checkbox to be set initially.  The idea is to check the box, the selected object dynamically updates and appears on the listview of another page.

Comment: Are you sure your DOM is ready at first load?

Comment: I am...that's why I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure your page is loaded into the DOM before doing this in the first place. Don't use document ready because it can trigger before jQM page is loaded into the DOM. Instead you should use proper [**jQuery Mobile page event**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600).

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
        var item=$(this);
        if(item.is(":checked")){    
            $('#myMenu').append( $('<li>').attr('class','ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c ui-li-last').append('test'));
            $('#myMenu').listview('refresh');
        }
        else {
            $( "#myMenu li:last-child" ).remove().closest( "[data-role=listview]" ).listview( "refresh" );  
        }
    });      
});
```

Where **`#index`** is an id of your page. Pageinit event is a jQuery Mobile alternative to classic jQuery document ready state.

Or like in my example you can bind a change event a little bit different:

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
```

This solution is called delegated binding and it don't care if element is loaded into the DOM or not.

And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/A8d3A/) a working example

**EDIT**

Working HTML example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
                $(document).on('change','#checkbox8',function(){
                    var item=$(this);
                    if(item.is(":checked")){    
                        alert('Checked');
                    } else {
                        alert('Unchecked');
                    }
                });      
            });     
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true">
                    <input id="checkbox8" name="addTo" data-theme="b" type="checkbox"/>
                    <label for="checkbox8"> add to</label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Gajotres.  The checkbox worked but change function did not.  I copied your code and made the page id change.

Comment: Then tell me something else. Do you you several HTML pages or one large HTML page with several jQM pages inside? And is your javascript initialized from the HEAD?

Comment: Its one large HTML page.  I initialized the js in the head (also tried at the end of the body).

Comment: If it is not a problem to you can you mail me your js file and I will fix it for you? Also can you try this:     $(document).on('change','#checkbox8',function(){ ? Basically I have replaced input[type = 'checkbox'] with #checkbox8.

Comment: Thanks Gajotres. All that's in my js file is what I posted initially...other than the js files from jquery mobile.

Comment: Then my code should work as you can see from my example. It is also a 1 HTML / multiple pages template. I will even create you a working HTML file.

Comment: everything works now.  I had to remove $('#myMenu').listview('refresh'); for the is checked.